# Question about the meaning of if condition

Tags: r, if-statement

Inside the "synthdid" package - [GitHub link](https://github.com/synth-inference/synthdid/), I found these codes.

My understanding is that they are trying to check if all columns in the list "keep" are in the "panel"'s columns and if the numbers of "keep"'s columns are smaller than "panel"'s columns.

But the actual "keep" has not only the column names but also the data under the columns.

```
panel.matrices = function(panel, unit = 1, time = 2, outcome = 3, treatment = 4, treated.last = TRUE) {
  # TODO: add support for covariates X, i.e. could keep all other columns
  keep = c(unit, time, outcome, treatment)
  if (!all(keep %in% 1:ncol(panel) | keep %in% colnames(panel))) {
    stop("Column identifiers should be either integer or column names in `panel`.")
  }
```

I believe that this is causing an error in my code, but if my understanding is different, could you please tell me the correct interpretation?

Comment: The if condition makes sense to me. column names must match on index of columns, or match on column names.

Comment: @zx8754 Thank you ! Yes, but my understanding is that the "keep" is the data and not the list of columns, right?

Comment: I've solved myself! I was specifying the column as panel$name for each argument in panel.matrices, but it seems that I should have entered the number of each column in the panel instead. Thanks for your help!